# jQuery AJAX: How to append a "SAVED" message and make it disappear after a second

Tags: jquery, append, fadeout

this is probably really simple for a jQuery expert.

I have <div id="form23"><form><textarea>blahblah</textarea><input type="button" value="save" onClick="saveCaption(23)"></form></div>

I want a SAVED message appear and disappear. But I DO NOT want to make the form or its elements disappear.

I have a AJAX call that is like the following.

```
function saveCaption(id) {

var queryString = $('#form'+id).formSerialize(); 

  $.ajax({

    type: "POST",

    url: "includes/ajax.php?request=saveCaption",

    data: queryString,

    success: function(response) {

      $('#form'+id).append(response)

    }

  });

  return false;

}
```

I was wondering.. I can append the response. But is there a way to fade it out right away after a second. Right now, it just keeps repeating and adding to the last append. I would like it to appear and disappear right after using fadeOut.

**UPDATE: I did this based on theIV and RaYell's response. It works.. but is it elegant?**

function saveCaption(id) {

```
var queryString = $('#form'+id).formSerialize(); 

  $.ajax({

    type: "POST",

    url: "includes/ajax.php?request=saveCaption",

    data: queryString,

    success: function(response) {

        $('#form'+id).append('<div id="message">'+response+'</div>');

        setTimeout(function () {

          $('#message').fadeOut(function(){

            $(this).remove();

          });

        }, 1000);

    }

  });

  return false;
```

}

Comment: I did this based on theIV and RaYell's response. But is it elegant?

function saveCaption(id) {


 var queryString = $('#form'+id).formSerialize(); 


   $.ajax({


  type: "POST",


  url: "includes/ajax.php?request=saveCaption",


  data: queryString,


  success: function(response) {


   $('#form'+id).append('<div id="message">'+response+'</div>');


   setTimeout(function () {


     $('#message').fadeOut(function(){


    $(this).remove();


     });


   }, 1000);


  }


   });


   return false;


}

Comment: I definitely can't answer if this is the most elegant way or not, as there probably is some other way to go about doing this. Glad it works, though! :) Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll want to do a combination of RaYell's answer above but use a remove in the fadeOut callback, or else it will continue to append to the previous append—at least, I think it will do that based on the way you phrased your question. Something like this could work:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $('selector').fadeOut(function(){
    $(this).remove();
  });
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 4):

After you append your message add this (inside success callback):

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('selector').fadeOut();
}, 1000);
```

Replace selector with something that will actually match your message.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand.. my response is "Saved". Hmmm.. would mind mind writing code within my code so I could understand?

Comment: @Scott, I think you'd better spend some time trying to understand what, exactly you need to do, since @RaYell gave you a quite good direction, on how you need to do it. SO is not the right place there people will write code for you.